# Azure data factory Sink data flow activity Fail

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My ADF pipeline is working great but for a file that is huge with probably around 300,000 rows added to a parquet file. I am getting the following error.

Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'FinaSink': Failed to execute dataflow with internal server error, please retry later. If issue persists, please contact Microsoft support for further assistance

I am not able to find any specific reason for the error. I have set the integration compute size to large also but that didnt help.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The above errors occur for some reasons like load and parallel execution.

Most of the times it got resolved for me when I change the Integration run time to a new one. In the dataflow activity create a new integration run time and assign it to the dataflow.

[image]

Change the integration runtime in the dataflow debug as well.

[image]

Go through this [Simialar Ask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1336989/getting-internal-server-error-in-azure-data-flow) by **@AnnuKumari-MSFT**

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, the issue is it’s happening in prod also that runs on a schedule for large files. I can’t change these settings during prod runs.

Comment: But I can try this in dev on a manual run and see if it resolves it. 
Also it’s working fine on files less than a 200,000 rows.

Comment: I had seen that article from Annu. So only one file is processing at a time, so parrell run isn’t happening. 
Plus compute size is large for integration runtime. As far as I know it can’t go more than large.

Comment: yeah, but regarding the above error, these are the only resolving steps I know. It happened lot of times for me and whenever I changed the integration run time to a new one it got resolved.

Comment: I tried doing that and still didnt resolve the issue, also that is a temporary fix. 
I am thinking if partitioning at a sink level can be a solution.

Comment: Did that worked?

Comment: Nope the solution above didn’t. I think we need another solution. Don’t know if partitioning at sink level will work or not. Don’t know how to do that also.

Comment: I think it's better to raise support ticket on this issue for deeper investigation.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, how do I do that?

Comment: Follow these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request#go-to-help--support-from-the-global-header